# Channel changing surround sound solution

Tags: audio

My computer and Television are in the same room on opposite walls. I would like to have them share a 5.1 surround sound system. The speakers will be oriented for the TV.

My computer has 6 ports for each channel for surround sound systems and an optical audio output. Both my TV and computer need to be connected via the optical port.

Is there software that sends rear left to front right, etc. Then the center speaker channel through the center speaker port rather than the optical audio.

I am running windows 10 and am looking for free software.

Comment: Please update your question to include the operating system.  Also, include whether you are looking for recommendations for gratis software or commercial software.

Comment: @user24174 (or user3718922), if you have lost access to your account, please use the 'contact us' link on the footer to contact the team so they can merge your accounts! :)